# Como convierto un string a un XML PHP?

Tags: php, xml, api

Hola tengo un strig con la siguiente forma

```
$xml = `<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GeneraTicket xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <idTicket>asdasdhghj-----</idTicket>
      <xmlTicket>
        <Comprobante Version="3.3" Serie="1028" Fecha="2017-12-20T01:24:39" FormaPago="01" CondicionesDePago="01" SubTotal="86.21" Descuento="0.00" Moneda="MXN" Total="100.00" TipoCambio="1" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="55764" Sello="" xmlns="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
  <Emisor Rfc="AAA010101AAA" Nombre="Emisor de Prueba" RegimenFiscal="601">
  </Emisor>
  <Receptor Rfc="" Nombre="" UsoCFDI="">
  </Receptor>
  <Conceptos>
    <Concepto ClaveProdServ="31133000A" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="Pieza" Descripcion="mi venta"
      ValorUnitario="86.21" Importe="86.21" Descuento="0.00">
      <Impuestos>
        <Traslados>
          <Traslado Base="86.21" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="13.79">
          </Traslado>
        </Traslados>
      </Impuestos>
    </Concepto>
  </Conceptos>
  <Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="13.79">
    <Traslados>
      <Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="13.79">
      </Traslado>
    </Traslados>
  </Impuestos>
</Comprobante>
      </xmlTicket>
    </GeneraTicket>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`;
```

Necesito convertirlo en un XML. 
No se si haya algo similar a **json_encode();**

igual ya intente de esta forma.

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<GeneraTicket xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></GeneraTicket>');

    $xml->xmlTicket->addChild('Comprobante');
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('Version', 3.3);
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('Serie', 1028);
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('Fecha', "2017-12-20T01:24:39");
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('FormaPago', '01');
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('CondicionesDePago', '01');
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('SubTotal', 86.21);
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('Descuento', 0.00);
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('Moneda', 'MXN');
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('Total', 100.00);
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('TipoCambio', 1);
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('TipoDeComprobante', 'I');
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('MetodoPago', 'PUE');
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('LugarExpedicion', 55764);
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('Sello', '');
    $xml->xmlTicket->Comprobante->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3');
```

Pero no funciona porque las letras que deben de ir en mayúsculas me las pasa a minúsculas.

```
<soap:envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:body>
        <generaticket xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <idticket>ADS----</idticket>
            <xmlticket>
                <comprobante xmlns="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" version="3.3" serie="1028" fecha="2017-12-20T01:24:39" formapago="01" condicionesdepago="01" subtotal="86.21" descuento="0" moneda="MXN" total="100" tipocambio="1" tipodecomprobante="I" metodopago="PUE" lugarexpedicion="55764" sello="" rfc="AAA010101AAA" nombre="Emisor de Prueba" regimenfiscal="601">
                    <emisor>
                        <receptor rfc="" nombre="" usocfdi="">
                            <conceptos>
                                <concepto claveprodserv="31133000" cantidad="1" claveunidad="H87" unidad="Pieza" descripcion="mi venta" valorunitario="86.21" importe="86.21" descuento="0">
                                    <impuestos></impuestos>
                                </concepto>
                            </conceptos>
                            <impuestos totalimpuestostrasladados="13.79">
                                <traslados base="86.21" impuesto="002" tipofactor="Tasa" tasaocuota="0.160000" importe="13.79">
                                    <traslado impuesto="2" tipofactor="Tasa" tasaocuota="0.16" importe="13.79"></traslado>
                                </traslados>
                            </impuestos>
                        </receptor>
                    </emisor>
                </comprobante>
            </xmlticket>
        </generaticket>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

Cuando consumo el servicio me dice que no encuentra las etiquetas.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un string and quieres construir un SimpleXMLElement solo necesitas pasar el string al constructor:

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GeneraTicket xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <idTicket>asdasdhghj-----</idTicket>
      <xmlTicket>
        <Comprobante Version="3.3" Serie="1028" Fecha="2017-12-20T01:24:39" FormaPago="01" CondicionesDePago="01" SubTotal="86.21" Descuento="0.00" Moneda="MXN" Total="100.00" TipoCambio="1" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="55764" Sello="" xmlns="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
  <Emisor Rfc="AAA010101AAA" Nombre="Emisor de Prueba" RegimenFiscal="601">
  </Emisor>
  <Receptor Rfc="" Nombre="" UsoCFDI="">
  </Receptor>
  <Conceptos>
    <Concepto ClaveProdServ="31133000A" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="Pieza" Descripcion="mi venta"
      ValorUnitario="86.21" Importe="86.21" Descuento="0.00">
      <Impuestos>
        <Traslados>
          <Traslado Base="86.21" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="13.79">
          </Traslado>
        </Traslados>
      </Impuestos>
    </Concepto>
  </Conceptos>
  <Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="13.79">
    <Traslados>
      <Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="13.79">
      </Traslado>
    </Traslados>
  </Impuestos>
</Comprobante>
      </xmlTicket>
    </GeneraTicket>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOD;

$xmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $xmlEl->asXML();
```